# Getting information of elements having same paths

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a path like this

```
<div class="accordion-group">
...
<span class="country-container u-text-ellipsis">
```

This container includes information on country and their relative values.

```
<a itemprop="url" class="country-name country-name--link" href="/top-websites/Switzerland"><Switzerland"</a>
```

I would like to extra the country from this.
I have also other information related to this country, that I would like to extract.
[image]
The path is

```
<div class="acccordion-group"> 
...
<span class="traffic-share-valueNumber js-countValue">3.95%</span>
```

The container includes several information with the same path as above. Example:

[image]

I tried with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="traffic-share-valueNumber js-countValue"]').get_attribute('textContent')
```

It works only for one value.

Can you explain me how to get all info about countries and their percentages? Happy to provide more info, if you need.
I would like to have this expected output (df):

```
Country       Percentage
Italy         87.81%
Switzerland   3.95%
Germany       2.75%
...           ...
```

Comment: can you share a link to the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the countries with

```
countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='country-name country-name--link']")
```

And the percentages with

```
percentages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='traffic-share-valueNumber js-countValue']")
```

Now you can iterate through the lists, get their texts and print or put into df.
To print the results you can do the following:

```
for country, percentage in zip(countries, percentages):
    print(country.text + '\t' + percentage.text)
```

Comment: I see cruisepandey answered you there. His answer didn't resolve your problem?

Comment: no, unfortunately his answer has not resolved my problem

Comment: OK, I'll try to take a look there.

Comment: I saw the question, the answer and the comments there. Not sure I understand what is the problem, what you trying to get and what is not working?